# How should I use maximumBy and compare to implement my function?

Tags: haskell, compare

I have to do an LZW compression in Haskell and I'm a bit stuck at searching the longest prefix because I have to use a combination of `maximumBy` and `compare` functions.

The function signature should be the following:

```
longest :: [(Int, String)] -> (Int, String)
```

Here are some tests that describe the requirements:

```
test_longest =
  [ longest [(30, "a"), (20, "abc"), (15, "ab")]  == (20, "abc")
  , longest [(30, "a"), (20, "abc"), (15, "abc")] == (15, "abc")
  ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

What I've came up with in trying to understand the problem is:

`longest (x:xs) = maximumBy (compare (length) x) xs`

but something is definitely off.

Comment: What is (20, "abc") ? Why longest returning what it is returning?

Comment: For LZW compression you have to build up a dictionary containing prefixes. (20, "abc") is the (<index in the dictionary>, <prefix>)

Comment: So have you written any code and what doesn't work about it?

Comment: Why in the second test case there is same prefix with different indices?

Comment: I'm not sure in which order should I combine the maximumBy and compare functions, and because of this I cannot see how should I split the input and what part of it should I give as parameter to compare, and what part of it to maximumBy

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have to prepare for the case when a prefix occurs more then once in the dictionary, in this case I have to return the lowest index, prefix pair

Comment: As pointed out by Eugene, your specs are ambiguous. In particular, why is the result of the second test `(15, "abc")` and not `(20, "abc")`? Also, edit your question and add whatever code you've come up with so far.

Comment: A function that passes your tests would be `longest = maximumBy $ \(l1, a1) (l2, a2) -> comparing length a1 a2 <> compare l2 l1`, be sure to note the order of arguments to `compare`.  This takes advantage of the fact that `Ordering` is a monoid (you'll need to import `Data.Monoid` and `Data.Ord` for this implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what will do:

```
import Data.List

compareEntry :: (Int, [Char]) -> (Int, [Char]) -> Ordering
compareEntry (i1, s1) (i2, s2)
    | len1 > len2 = GT   -- First compare the length of the strings
    | len1 < len2 = LT
    | i1 < i2 = GT       -- If they are equal, compare the indices
    | i2 > i1 = LT       -- (mind the reversed order, since you want the lowest index)
    | otherwise = EQ
    where 
        len1 = length s1
        len2 = length s2

longest = maximumBy compareEntry
```

It can be written in a shorter but less readable way.

Comment: Thanks alot, it helped me alot. This is what I came up with `longest xs = maximumBy selectPrefix xs
 where
  selectPrefix (i1, s1) (i2, s2) = compare (length s1) (length s2)` now the only question is how do I get rid of the selectPrefix function

Comment: And one other thing, in my solution above, why do I have `selectPrefix (i1, s1) (i2, s2)`, where do the 2 tuples come from, which function is calling which one?

Comment: In your solution the `selectPrefix` does not deal with the case the length is equal. To get rid of this function you can use the lambda notation (anonymous function)

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of the solution by @Eugene Sh:

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

longest = maximumBy (comparing (length . snd) <> flip (comparing fst))
```

Comment: ... [using](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) `instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) where (f <> g) x = f x <> g x` and hence `(f <> g) x y = f x y <> g x y`, and [`instance Semigroup Ordering`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup)